# R Using grep() to extract characters

Tags: r

In the link below is a list (of warning messages):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pz-jSkqU5nG_ipaezFCvWNI6WHgekAdE/view?usp=sharing

And I am trying to get:

1. Only at the start of the string,
2. Where this pattern exists "x = ECC    ",
3. Retrieve only the "ECC" portion.

I was successful on this test:

[regex.com](https://regex101.com/r/Ry550F/1)

But R doesn't work with this code:

```
grep("(?<=\\A\"x\\s=\\s')[A-Z]*", names(warnings), value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
```

#> character(0)

What's not working?

Comment: It is the same but I used your answer on different "warning list" and returned a list of NA's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this data you have additional spaces in the text (Eg - `"x = 'GEN           '`) hence the pattern does not match. We may switch to `str_match` here :

```
stringr::str_match(names(warnings), "x\\s=\\s'(\\w+)\\s+'")[, 2]
# [1] "ECC"  "ECC"  "ECOM" "ECOM" "ETX"  "ETX"  NA     NA     NA     "FEI" 
#[11] "FEI"  "GEN"  "GEN"  NA     NA     NA     "SAND" "SAND" NA     NA    
#[21] NA     "STAR" "STAR" NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: Thanks!  I struggled with grep(), lookforward and lookbehind for so long.  I did notice the additional spaces and assumed trimws() will take care of them.  Thanks!